# Python how to call function base on different input value in a class?

Tags: python, function, class, call

I have a class with multiple functions. Given an `id` outside the class, is it possible to call a function based on the id value?

For example,

if `id = 1`, run `fun1`

if `id = 2`, run `fun2`

```
class functions:
    def fun1(self, para1, para2, para3):
        pass
    def fun2(self, para1, para2, para3):
        pass
    ·
    ·
    ·
```

To be more precise, I'd like to call these functions in such a way.
Here in another class

```
id = x
fun(x, para1, para2, para3)
```

Then `fun(x, para1, para2, para3)` will call different `fun` in the `functions` class base on `x`

Comment: Yes, just create a mapping where this `id` will be a key, e.g. `functions = {1: fun1, 2: fun2}`. Then retrieve function using id and call it `functions[1]()`.

Comment: It's a little more complicated because they're methods.

Comment: Are these static methods or instance methods? Instance methods need a `self` argument.

Comment: @Barmar They would be instance methods.

Comment: @user8314628, why don't you just define one more method `fun()` which contains bunch of `if id == 1: fun1()` statements?

Comment: @Olvin Roght That's a good idea.

Comment: @user8314628 you can also implement `functions()[id]` logic by overriding [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map the ID to a method.

```
func_map = {1: functions.fun1, 2: functions.fun2}
f = functions()
id = int(input("Enter function id:"))

if id in func_map:
    params = input("Enter parameters separated by space:").split()
    func_map[id](f, *params)
else:
    print("Invalid function")
```

Comment: Ok, this is similar to what I did. I used `if` statement instead. But it has 7 cases and looks tedious.

Comment: @user8314628, it's absolutely okay to have dozen of `if` if it's necessary.

Comment: @user8314628 Making it data-driven simplifies the code.